# POS: How do I sum the price per item to get the total price?

Tags: java, pos

(Its not finished yet.)
I don't know how to get the total price after asking the user for their order. Example: I ordered 5 Piatos, and I typed `end` to show the result or  total, but it just says 20 but it should be 100 because 20+20+20+20+20 = 100. How do I sum those individual prices so it shows the correct total price without changing the way to order items? (Which is selecting only the letters provided for each item.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Point_Of_Sale_System_Real {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Intro();
    }

    public static void Intro(){  

        int Piatos = 20, Vcut = 20;

        double itemtotal = 0, itemtotalvisible, itemlone = 0;

        String Ia = "a";
        String Ib = "b";

        System.out.println("Enter the letter that matches the item here: ");
        System.out.println("Type \"End\" to stop selecting from the menu." );

        String itemselect = "";
        do {
            itemselect = sc.nextLine();   
            if (itemselect.equalsIgnoreCase(Ia)){
                itemlone = 0 + Piatos;
            }
            else if (itemselect.equalsIgnoreCase(Ib)){
                itemlone = 0 + Vcut;
            }
        }
        while (!itemselect.equalsIgnoreCase("end"));

        itemtotalvisible = itemlone + 0;
        System.out.println("Total" + itemtotalvisible);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you make a selection in the `do-while` loop, you need to update `itemtotalvisible`. You are merely assigning the last value of `itemlone` to `itemtotalvisible`. Hence because the last item you selected was *Piatos*, `itemtotalvisible` equals the value of one *Piatos* item.

The below code is not a complete answer, but hopefully enough to help you fix your code.

```java
double itemtotalvisible = 0;
String itemselect = "";
do {
    itemselect = sc.nextLine();
    if (itemselect.equalsIgnoreCase(Ia)){
        itemlone = 0 + Piatos;
    }
    else if (itemselect.equalsIgnoreCase(Ib)){
        itemlone = 0 + Vcut;
    }
    itemtotalvisible += itemlone;
}while (!itemselect.equalsIgnoreCase("end"));

System.out.println("Total" + itemtotalvisible);
```

Comment: It worked! It now sums up. But I got another problem on this part of my code again. I did what you did but if I entered 3 a's (which is 3 Piatos....... so 20+20+20)  it says 80, but it's supposed to be 60. What it does is it adds an extra 20 again. If I do 20+20+30 it goes 100, it's suppose to be 70 but adds the last number as an extra so it goes 100.